# NumericUpDown in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, numericupdown

I have a WPF window that holds a bunch of numbers. Or to use nicer words: Each column is bound to one int property. Now I want to have a nice way to change some of the numbers and I was hoping that I can use a numericUpDown control. Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Sample code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Where `wpfToolkit` is:

```
xmlns:wpfToolkit="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
```

In this example I use `IntegerUpDown` control from [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks, @kmatyaszek.  Can you explain why the `UpdateSourceTrigger` is necessary.  I find I don't need it when the spinner its not in a datagrid, but when it is in a datagrid it doesn't work without it.